Yubikey/GPG Ed25519 signing without knowledge of the public key
Lets assume the following scenario:
We have an Ed25519 secret key generated on a hardware device (like a Yubikey). Lets assume it is protected by the device and cannot be exported. The device can - in principle - be instructed to sign messages (using the internally stored secret key) without the secret key ever leaving the device.
Now my question is if there is a way, preferably using GPG, to sign a message without access to the corresponding public key (and ideally also without access to the key fingerprint)? I am struggling to find a way to instruct GPG to do this, various tutorials mention that I need to import the public key to GPG first, to get use the fingerprint as reference when I instruct GPG to sign with the secret key (stored on the Yubikey).
A bit of context: In the application I am considering, signing (actually with a number of different Yubikeys) is done on a highly isolated offline system. Fetching the public keys from a key server would therefore be impossible. Connecting, e.g., a USB stick with the public key would be undesirable as well.

Can you tell us why you'd want to do this? In principle the signing can be performed without the public key and otherwise it can be calculated from the private key. However, signature formats such as PGP usually store the public key with the signature [EDIT: I think PGP just stores the key ID with the signature though, after a quick lookup as I had forgot].

My motivation for exploring this is the interaction with a minimal & isolated offline system where the signing with different keys should be done at. But I believe this would be useful in other contexts as well. For example, say a user want to create a backup of a key (pair) and decides to put it on a Yubikey which is pin-protected & stored in some secure location. In the user's mental model, having the secret key on the Yubikey is a proper backup, but in practice it turns out that the device is useless without being able to recover the public key from somewhere.

Ah, OK, that's an interesting reason. I'm bit bit muffed that the YubiKey doesn't return the public key value. It can be calculated from the secret after all for EdDSA as the key pair generation starts off by calculating the secret key and the public key doesn't use the RNG. However, signing is more complex than calculation of the public key even if it relies on a similar calculation, so I don't think you can start off with that.

Wait a moment... How are you going to identify the private key exactly? You do want to know what you are signing for, right? I do see a GET PUBLIC KEY command for Yubikey HSM 2 which just requires the two byte Object ID. That should normally be available especially if the key pair is generated on the device. Please do specify which exact device you are using in the question. [EDIT: is this a question about having the software to select the right private key without pubkey?]

I am using the normal Yubikey (v5, not the HSM version).
The public key is automatically imported to GPG on my PC when I initially generate the key on the Yubikey.
Using the command gpg --card-status, I can see the handles of the keys on the Yubikey (e.g, 6E93 0B93 7342 CE9F 8DC4  6C8C FBD9 5957 83F6 DB47, I would assume that is a hash of the public key).
To sign a message with the Yubikey, I specify this handle in the GPG sign command and input my PIN. But that only works as long as I am on the same PC (where the public key / handle was imported to GPG during key generation).

Regarding [EDIT: is this a question about having the software to select the right private key without pubkey?]
Yes, preferably without modifying & recompiling standard GPG.

I think I understand the question now. However, to me it seems that it asks to identify and use a private key without considering the primary element (the public key / certificate) that is used to identify it in the first place. I'd be surprised if that's part of any software package by default. Writing down and importing the key ID, possibly even manually or using a QR code or something seems to most logical solution.

Thank you for you attempt to help so far!
To be clear, I can easily get the key fingerprint (and keygrip) from the Yubikey. I am struggling with the next step though, importing that fingerprint / keygrip into GPG such that I can actually sign something.
